# Inheritance of SetupFixture of a base class from different projects (nunit)

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying to use a base SetupFixtureClass to be called in every of my projects within the solution.

I got my abstract class TestFixtureSetupBase which has no namespace and lies in project a.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public abstract class TestFixtureSetupClass
{
     [FixtureSetup]
     public void init(){myRandomMethod()};

     public virtual void myRandomMethod(){};
}
```

and I got another class from project b which inherits from this class like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class OtherClassOfOtherProject : TestFixtureSetupClass
{
     public override void myRandomMethod(){...};

     [Test]
     public void randomTest(){...}
}
```

However, neither the Setup nor myRandomMethod is getting called in this project.

What do I have to take care of  for getting my desired result? It seems that I fulfill the requirements mentioned in the [nunit-documentation.](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.5)

Edit/Update: What I try to do is: Build up my environment once, in TestFixtureSetUp. It it fails, I'd like to get a good exception. Therefore I followed an example shown by sandshadow here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121991/1484047. So I'd store the exception and throw it in setup of every single executed test as otherwise no exception will be shown at all (there would only be s.th. like "SetUpFixture failed" without any explanation).

Comment: Are you running the tests from the command line? With what arguments?

Comment: I'm running them with ReSharper - no commands, just basic Debug-Functionality

Comment: well, this is not only a resharper problem as our build-server is not using resharper and we got the same problem there as well

Comment: What is your build server using? It is better to provide these details in the question. NUnit itself supports this, other runners may have bugs. The thing to understand is there are many runner implementations that each have their own quirks.

Comment: Based on your edit, it sounds like what you're trying to do is answered in that linked answer.  What about that answer is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your code with NUnit 2.6.2 I get different results.  The GUI runner fails to run the test and gives this error:

> ConsoleApplication4.OtherClassOfOtherProject.randomTest:
>   TestFixtureSetUp method not allowed on a SetUpFixture

Which makes sense.  Your base class `TestFixtureSetupClass` has the [`SetUpFixture` attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.6.3), which means "this class has a methods on it marked with `SetUp` or `TearDown` that should be run before/after any other tests in this namespace."  This is not the place to include a method with the [`TestFixtureSetUp` attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.6.3), which means "run this method before any tests in the fixture (class)"

Since I think you're just incorrectly mixing attributes, what do you want to happen?

1. I want `myRandomMethod` to be called once before any test in my tests' namespace:

   ```
   [SetUpFixture]
   public class TestFixtureSetupClass
   {
       [SetUp]
       public void init()
       {
           myRandomMethod();
       }

       public virtual void myRandomMethod() { }
   }
   ```
2. I want `myRandomMethod` to be called once before any test in a derived class, for each derived class:

   ```
   public abstract class TestFixtureSetupClass
   {
       [TestFixtureSetUp]
       public void init()
       {
           myRandomMethod();
       }

       public virtual void myRandomMethod() { }
   }
   ```

Note the differences: class-level attributes, the `abstract` keyword, and attributes on `init`.

Comment: Thanks! What I actually want to do is shown by sandshadow here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23121991/1484047 - I'd like to have some common things setup ONCE for my namespace and if it failed, it should be mentioned in the SetUp.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as I tried exactly this construction "TestFixtureSetUp" and "SetUp" two hours ago and it worked great - my exception was thrown in the testFixtureSetUp and it was raised every time SetUp was called. However, I can't reproduce it :<

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of [resharper unit test inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629926/resharper-unit-test-inheritance). The first comment indicates that this is a Resharper bug that was fixed in release 5.1.1.

Comment: as I mentioned in the comment: I've seen the link you suggested and nope, it's not a duplicate. I'm using a newer version so it should not occure if it is related to my problem